# Parametrizing a "surface" that is actually a curve, then integrating to find the area?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find a parametrization of the surface $x^2-y^2=1$, where $x>0$, $-1 \leq y \leq1$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1$. Use your answer to express the area of the surface as an integral.

I'm confused because in the past I've only seen parametrizing as a change of variables... (or in the case of a graph $z=f(x,y)$, letting $x=u, y=v, z=f(u,v))$.

If I make $z=f(x,y)=x^2-y^2=1$, then I just have a hyperbola, which isn't a surface in $\mathbb R^3$.

I let $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2=1$ and constrained the graph to a section $x>0$, $-1\leq y \leq 1$, getting a portion of a sideways parabola on the $xy$ plane. This section of the curve is stacked from  $0 \leq z \leq 1$.

I have an image for what the surface looks like but I don't see any obvious parametrization.

Comment: It *is* a surface because $z$ is arbitrary. Parametrize your curve $x^2-y^2=1$ in the $xy$-plane your favorite way, and then introduce $z$ as a second variable.

Comment: Not sure if I understand... so could I do $u = x^2-y^2=1$ and $v=z$? Then integrate over $0 \leq v \leq 1$? But how would I form my interval for $u$?

Comment: Remember, the Hyperbolic Functions must be good for something!

Comment: No, either you need $x=\cosh u$, $y=\sinh u$ — if you know what those are — or you need $y=u$, $x=\sqrt{1+u^2}$ for part of it.